# Adding users to firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm having a bit of trouble adding users to Firebase. If anyone could help me out with this, it would be significantly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
var myRootRef = Firebase(url:"https://plattrapp.firebaseio.com/users")
        myRootRef.createUser(emailSignUpEntered, password: passwordSignUpEntered,
            withValueCompletionBlock: { error, result in

                if error != nil {
                    // There was an error creating the account
                } else {
                    let uid = result["uid"] as? String
                    println("Successfully created user account with uid: \(uid)")
                }
        })
```

It does display in the println statement within my debugger that a user has been created, but doesn't actually display within my firebase database.

Anything I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Authentication does not automatically create any information about the user in the associated database.

Most applications end up creating this information from their own code under a top-level `users` node. This is covered in the section called ["Storing User Data" in the Firebase programming guide for iOS](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing).

It is in general a good idea to read the Firebase documentation on the topic that you are working on. It will prevent a lot of grey/lost hair and wasted time.

Comment: Oh ok I understand what you are saying. So is Firebase only for authenticating users? I am going through their documentation right now and I don't see anything which allows secure user sign up capabilities. If Firebase is not for creating information for users, what kind of language would be the best to create users? I was thinking of Python or Ruby