# Accessing nested unique key values in firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I'm sure this is a trivial question but can't seem to figure out how to access the players id in this firebase array. I need to be able to access all the players id's, and if the current users.id established at login matches one of the players id's firebase array then those games will be looped over with ng-repeat. I know how to accomplish the latter, I just can't figure out to access the players id's inside the unique id's;  Hopefully that makes sense. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

[image: Firebase]

## JS

### (this is some of the code associated with my problem)

```
game.controller('games.controller', ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', 'Auth', '$firebaseArray','Fire', function ($scope, $state, $stateParams, auth, $firebaseArray, fire) {

  $scope.games = $firebaseArray(fire.child('games'));
  $scope.view = 'listView';

  $scope.setCurrentGame = function(game) {
    $scope.currentGame = game;
  };

  $scope.createGame = function() {
    if ($scope.format == 'Match Play') {
      $scope.skinAmount = 'DOES NOT APPLY';
      $scope.birdieAmount = 'DOES NOT APPLY';
    }
    $scope.games.$add({
      name: $scope.gameName,
      host: $scope.user.name,
      date: $scope.gameDate,
      location: {
        course: $scope.courseName,
        address: $scope.courseAddress
      },
      rules: {
        amount: $scope.gameAmount,
        perSkin: $scope.skinAmount,
        perBirdie: $scope.birdieAmount,
        format: $scope.format,
        holes : $scope.holes,
        time: $scope.time
      }
    })
    $state.go('games');
  };

  $scope.addPlayer = function(game) {
    $firebaseArray(fire.child('games').child(game.$id).child('players')).$add({
      id : $scope.user.id,
      name : $scope.user.name,
      email : $scope.user.email
    });
  }

  // swap DOM structure in games state
  $scope.changeView = function(view){
    $scope.view = view;
  }

}]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're violating two common Firebase rules here:

1. if an entity has a natural, unique id, store it with that id as its key
2. don't nest lists

I'm guessing #1 happened because you are storing the players using `$firebaseArray.$add()`. Instead of repeating myself, I'll list a few questions that deal with the same problem:

- [Firebase make user object from auth data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31822804/firebase-make-user-object-from-auth-data/31822957#31822957)
- [Adding users to firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31777630/adding-users-to-firebase/31777825#31777825)
- [How to bypass unique ID and reference child nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31757307/how-to-bypass-unique-id-and-reference-child-nodes/31763235#31763235)

The nesting of lists is a common mistake. By having the players stored under each game, you can never load the data for a list of games, without also loading all players for all games. For this reason (and others) it is often better to store the nested list under its own top-level:

```
games
    -Juasdui9
        date:
        host: 
    -Jviuo732
        date:
        host: 
games_players
    -Juasdui9
       -J43as437y239
           id: "Simplelogin:4"
           name: "Anthony"
    -Jviuo732
       ....
users
```

Comment: Thanks, Frank. When I bring the players out to the top-level how would I go about tying them to game they entered?

Comment: If you carefully look at my sample data structure, you'll see that the same id exists both under `games` and `games_players`. So to find the information about a game, you look it up under `/games/$gameid`. To find its players, you look up `/games_players/$gameid`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen firebase also sugguest to flat data as much we can. Your structure will not increase look ups?