# How to persist a success icon in the view after modal function with AngularJS and UI-Bootstrap? (Plunker)

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularfire

I'm making something that works similarly to [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rZTnqBMly9w7oG9II7PM?p=preview) that I created.

In my app I'm using Firebase/AngularFire.

In the plunker you can see that when you check-in to a meeting, the icon changes to a success icon. In my app this is where I store that info in Firebase like this:

```
$scope.join = function(hash) {
        console.log(hash);

        var ref = dbRef.ref('meetings/'+hash+'/users')

        var meetingInfo = $firebaseArray(ref);

        meetingInfo.$add({
            date: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
            user_name: $scope.name,
            user: $scope.currentUser
        }).then(function(ref) {
            var key = ref.key;
            var index = meetingInfo.$indexFor(key);
            console.log(key, index);

            $uibModalInstance.close();
        });
    };
```

So the data gets added into Firebase and then the modal closes.

I also have a similar controller and view for listing out the meetings just like in the plunker.

In the plunker I send a variable through `$rootScope` so it's accessible in the `listingController`. That works, but as you can see I can only check-in to one meeting, and after I refresh or check-in to another meeting, the check-mark disappears.

I would like to know how to persist this change so that anytime I check-in to a meeting the check-mark will stay. I'm thinking that I need to edit something in my listing controller so that when it grabs the data, it can check to see if someone has checked in to the meeting, and display the checkmark, so here is my Firebase list controller:

```
app.controller('listController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$firebaseArray', '$firebaseObject', '$uibModal', function($scope, $rootScope, $firebaseArray, $firebaseObject, $uibModal) {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref('meetings');

    var list = $firebaseObject(ref);

    list.$loaded().then(function(data) {
        $scope.lobbies = list;
    });

}]);
```

**EDIT**

The way Firebase stores the data is like this:

```
---meetings
------random hash (key)
---------date
---------name
---------attendees
------------random hash
---------------date
---------------name
```

When I do my ng-repeat it's like this: `ng-repeat="(key, meeting) in meetings"` so I can access the meeting data like `meeting.name`. How should I go about accessing the attendees to check if the current user is in the meeting?

**SOLUTION**

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31868286/accessing-nested-unique-key-values-in-firebase) helped me out a lot in addition to the HTML snippet that idan provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide where you keep this data and how.
You can, for example, hold a list of attendees in the meeting. Something like:

```
{
  users: {
    userid1: {
      name: 'Someone'
    },
    userid2: {
      name: 'Someone else'
    }
    // ...
  },
  meetings: {
    meetingid1: {
      location: 'Somewhere',
      title: 'Gala',
      attendees: {
        userid1: true,
        userid3: true
        // ...
      }
    }
    // ...
  }
}
```

Then you can check if a user attends a meeting to change the button.

Also the `ng-if` there to change buttons seems too much. You can use `ng-class` on the button and icon, then you'll have only one button instead of two.

```
<button class="btn btn-sm" ng-click="open(meeting)" ng-class="user.$id in meeting.attendees ? 'btn-success' : 'btn-primary'">
  <i class="fa" ng-class="user.$id in meeting.attendees ? 'fa-check' : 'fa-sign-in'"></i>
</button>
```

One more thing: strongly recommend to read [Angular style guide 1](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) and [Angular style guide 2](https://github.com/toddmotto/angular-styleguide). Both contain great tips to help you maintain your app easily.

Comment: This made me understand the problem better, I didn't know exactly what I needed to do. I updated my question now to see how I can use the line that you provided: `user.$id in meeting.attendees`

Comment: Actually since this was more of a Firebase question I went looking and found this question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31868286/accessing-nested-unique-key-values-in-firebase. It's actually exactly what I was looking for I just didn't know how to ask it. However that small snippet of html code you provided helped me out so I'm marking this as answer.